# How do I bind keypress up in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
events:{
    'kepressUp input#price': 'submitForm'
},
```

How would I detect keypress up ?

WHen someone types something in the price section, I want to automatically submit the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kepressUp` event doesn't exists. You can use [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), [`keydown`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) and [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)

```
events:{
    'keyup input#price': 'submitForm'
},
```